# How do you change the fetched image of a PDF uploaded into WordPress Media Library?

Tags: images

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I uploaded a PDF into the WordPress media library. I am then taking that link and using it on another platform LearnWorlds. LearnWorlds pulls the metadata that is fetched from media that is uploaded into the WordPress Library. Right now it is only pulling the actual pdf not any image- ex the cover of the PDF. LearnWorlds is telling me I have to change the metadata on the image. How do you do that in WordPress so that when the item is fetched the cover shows too?

Answer (score 0):

If Learnworlds is extracting the image out of the PDF file, this isn't something WordPress is involved in and the necessary steps would mean changing the PDF file itself. The metadata is the PDF files metadata, not the post meta of the attachment.

Given that you're taking a direct URL of the PDF and passing it to LearnWorlds, WordPress is not involved in the process once the file is uploaded to the media library. There is no solution to your problem that involves WordPress or WordPress knowledge.

This may be of help:
https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/pdf-properties-metadata.html

Otherwise you will need to look at general PDF solutions, there is no WordPress specific solution to your problem, and you may be severely limiting the possible resources you can find by only searching within WordPress expertise

Comment: I also can't find any evidence that there is a specific cover image function in PDFs, the thumbnail is just the first page, so the answer may be that you need to create a cover page with the graphic you want and set it as the first page. Eitherway the solution to your problem has nothing to do with WordPress.